# Seaborn barplot - Set y-axis as Integer Ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I'm trying to create a horizontal seaborn barplot with the y-axis as integer ticks. When I attempt it I get the following error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`.  The integers are quoted in a list `y=['100', '200']` so I thought they would be interpreted as string.  If I add one ore more alphabets to the integers it works fine but not the desired labels I want. How can I use the list of integers as the y-axis ticks and avoid this error?

Does **NOT** Work:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 2))

sns.barplot(y=['100', '200'], x=[100, 75],
            color="#e9ffe1", orient='h')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Works:**

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 2))

sns.barplot(y=['100s', '200s'], x=[100, 75],
            color="#e9ffe1", orient='h')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Desired Output:**

[image]

Comment: Did you upgrade to the latest seaborn version (0.10)? Also, you need `orient='h'` for a horizontal barplot. You can also just use integers instead of strings for the y-axis, leaving out the quotes.

Comment: Upgrading Seaborn to 0.10 did indeed fix the problem. I was on 0.90. Thanks, I was losing my mind over this simple thing.

Comment: Both your codes are identical. What is the difference?

Comment: Copy paste error. The one that works only worked when a string was included with the integer. Updated to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to Seaborn 0.10 to resolve issue.

```
pip install seaborn --upgrade
```